# Azure Log Analytics Software inventory for on Prem Servers

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, oms

I'm trying to follow the below Article(s) to configure Azure Log Analytics for on prem servers as well as Azure servers to get a list of installed software.

It works well on Azure VMs but not on non-Azure VMs. All servers are successfully sending Heartbeats but only the Azure VMs are showing a list of installed Software when running the below query:

ConfigurationData
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by SoftwareName, Computer
| where ConfigDataType == "Software"
| summarize count() by Computer

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-tutorial-installed-software

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/

Anyone knows how to get the On-Prem to show a list of installed Software?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution!!

For azure its being done automatically but for non azure we need to go manually in our automation account and check on "Enable Inventory" and here we have 3 options (see my screen shots).

From Home --> Automation Accounts --> Automate-%ID%-WEU --> Inventory

[image]

[image]

may be useful for the Documentation as its a must for non-azure vms

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-tutorial-installed-software

CHECK MY COMMENTS AT THE BOTTOM